# How to use Docker in Windows ?

Tags: docker, windows-10

I have few questions about using Docker in Win 10 Pro. 
I have already installed Docker, but I need help to create environment to develop using php.

If my idea is wrong, please, correct it.

I need a any linux OS as image base, on it I need php, nginx, git, composer, mysql etc. Do I will use this image to create containers for my projects.

Where I can download this image/configuration ?

Or I don't need linux OS ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to **[official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/)**.

Here's some documentation that I think it can help you about this particular subject :

- [Create a base image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#creating-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch)
- [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)